# PHP bucle creando variables dinámicas

Tags: php, laravel, php7, laravel-7, php-5.6

Tengo este código que quiero ejecutarlo 4 veces asignando los valores a 4 variables que serán

trimestre1,trimestre,trimestre3 y trimestre4

El código de forma individual es algo como esto

```
        $trimestre1 = Calculos::where('valor_id',$valor->id)
        ->whereRaw(
            "(fecha >= ? AND fecha <= ?)",
            [$fromDatet1." 00:00:00", $toDatet1." 23:59:59"]
        )->get();

        $trimestre2 = Calculos::where('valor_id',$valor->id)
            ->whereRaw(
                "(fecha >= ? AND fecha <= ?)",
                [$fromDatet2." 00:00:00", $toDatet2." 23:59:59"]
            )->get();
```

Y lo he intentado poner en un bucle para construir las variables trimestre1 hasta trimestre4 y las variables fromdatet1 ....fromdatet4 y la variable todate1...todate4

```
            for ($i=1;$i<5;$i++) {

            $trimestre.$i = Calculos::where('valor_id',$valor->id)
                ->whereRaw(
                    "(fecha >= ? AND fecha <= ?)",
                    [$fromDatet1." 00:00:00", $toDatet1." 23:59:59"]
                )->get();

        }
```

Pero esto no es correcto.
Alguna sugerencia de como hacerlo?

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pienso que lo suyo es usar un array asociativo `trimestres[trimestre1: valor...`. Pero sí, PHP permite usar valores de variables para crear otras variables, se usa el símbolo `$$`.

Mira este ejemplo:

```
for($i=1; $i<5; $i++) {
    $numtrim = "trimestre".$i;
    $$numtrim = $i*100;   //estás usando $trimestre1, $trimestre2...
}
echo $trimestre1;
echo $trimestre2;
echo $trimestre3;
echo $trimestre4;
```

Verás que se imprimen los valores 100, 200, 300, 400 sin error alguno. Las variables `$trimetres1` a `$trimetres4` sí existen.

```
echo $trimetre1."\n";
echo $trimetre2."\n";
echo $trimetre3."\n";
echo $trimetre4."\n";
```